# Smarty echo of array variable with "-" in its name

Tags: php, smarty

I have variable that in PHP controller looks like

`$data['content']['mods']['HTML-FORM-END']['html']`

It is passed nicely in smarty, but when I try to show it any of these ways, it shows either 0 (assumes minus as operator and does some math), or says "unrecognized tag"

`{$data.content.mods.HTML-FORM-BEGIN.html}

{$data.content.mods['HTML-FORM-BEGIN']['html']}

{$data.content.mods.HTML-FORM-BEGIN.html}

{$data.content.mods.HTML-FORM-BEGIN.html}`

How can i print it without renaming array key in controller?

Comment: Today I learned smarty accesses multi-dimensional arrays with dots.

Answer (score 1):

Your example references 'HTML-FORM-END' in your controller but 'HTML-FORM-BEGIN' in your view but I'll assume that isn't your issue and both exist.  How about this?

```
{$data[content][mods][HTML-FORM-BEGIN][html]}
```

From what I can find it appears that the only way to get down into a multi-dimensional array in Smarty is with loops.  Perhaps instead you could split your array into assigns in your controller to provide easy access:

```
foreach($data['content']['mods'] as $key => $values) {
  $smarty->assign('content_mods_' . $key, $values['html'];
}
```

and then you could reference them in your template like this:

```
{$content_mods_HTML-FORM-BEGIN}
{$content_mods_HTML-FORM-END}
// etc.
```